# comment_post action hook running on page load instead of after a comment is posted

Tags: comments, comment-form, comments-template

I am trying to call a function after a comment is saved to the database, see below...

```
add_action('comment_post', 'myFunction', 10, 2); 
do_action('comment_post', $comment_ID, $comment_approved);
```

I have placed this code in my `comments.php` file. `myFunction` is defined in `functions.php` and is shown below

```
function myFunction($comment_ID, $comment_approved){
    Analytics::track('Posted comment!');
}
```

The problem is that this function is getting called every time a page containing the comment form is loaded not just when a comment is posted...

Any thoughts on why this is happening???

I guess a work around could be to call the function on page load only when the page is being loaded from `wp-comments-post.php` but I don't know where to even start trying to achieve this...

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your action is called whenever `comments.php` loads because you're explicitly running it with `do_action`. Both the function and `add_action` should be in `functions.php`, and `do_action` should be removed entirely.